# Diretiva não funciona com propriedades dinâmicas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Opa, galera. Estou desenvolvendo umas diretivas customizadas por aqui, e elas precisam ter propriedades adicionadas de forma flexível (tipo um ng-class). Consegui desenvolver o mecanismo para fazer isso, contudo, me deparei com um problema bizarro: ele adiciona a propriedade mas a mesma não faz efeito algum

Estou testando com as libs [angular-input-masks](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) e [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask). A minha diretiva adiciona corretamente os atributos, porém, os mesmos não fazem efeito.

Particularmente, acredito que isso é algum problema de tempo de script ou algo do gênero. O que reforça esse meu pensamento é que quando eu adiciono os atributos direto no template html, funciona.

Já tentei usar `$scope.$apply()`, mas deu ruim :(.

Teste: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ae7oABrzAACjr9NDYLhK?p=preview

Desde já agradeço.

**Diretiva de propriedades dinâmicas**

```
app.directive('mdiAttrs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: (scope, elem) => {
            let attrs = scope.mdiCustomProperties || {};

            Object.keys(attrs).forEach(attrKey => elem.attr(attrKey, attrs[attrKey]));
        }
    };
});
```

**Diretiva do Input**

```
app.directive('mdiInput', () => {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/mdi-input.html',
        scope: (() => {
            const inputScope = angular.copy(directiveScopeModel);

            inputScope.mdiType = '@?';
            inputScope.mdiPlaceholder = '@?';
            inputScope.mdiTitle = '@?';

            return inputScope;
        })(),
        controller: $scope => {
            $scope.isLoading = false;
            $scope.mdiType = $scope.mdiType || 'text';
        }
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
<label class="mdi-directive">
    <span class="mdi-label">{{mdiLabel}}</span>
    <input type="{{mdiType}}" 
        class="mdi-component" 
        ng-model="mdiModel"
        ng-click="mdiClick(this)"
        ng-blur="mdiBlur(this)"
        ng-class="{'loading': isLoading}"
        ng-disabled="isLoading"
        placeholder="{{mdiPlaceholder}}"
        ng-required="mdiRequired"
        title="{{mdiTitle}}"
        mdi-attrs="mdiCustomProperties"> 
</label>
```

**Chamada da diretiva**

```
<mdi-input mdi-model="mdiInputModel" 
        mdi-blur="doRequest"
        mdi-label="MDI Input Directive"
        mdi-custom-properties="{'ui-mask': '(999) 999-9999'}"
        mdi-required="true">
 </mdi-input>
```

Comment: Tem como criar um exemplo demonstrando o problema, HDeiro?

Comment: Tá na mão: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ae7oABrzAACjr9NDYLhK?p=preview